# Type annotation for values of attributes of an Enum class instance

Tags: python, enums, python-typing

In python, I have the following instance of the Enum class:

```
class Colour(Enum):
    Red = "1"
    Blue = "2"
    Green = "3"
```

I have a function that takes a value of an attribute of this class, i.e. one of `Colour.Red.value`, `Colour.Blue.value` or `Colour.Green.value`:

```
def myfunc(input_str):
    return(input_str)
```

How do I define the type annotation for `input_str` in this case?

Pylance returns a warning when using `input_str: Literal[Colour.Red.value, Colour.Blue.value, Colour.Green.value]`: "Type arguments for "Literal" must be None, a literal value (int, bool, str, or bytes), or an enum value". I understand from [PEP-0586](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/#legal-parameters-for-literal-at-type-check-time) that `Literal[Colour.Red, Colour.Blue, Colour.Green]` would be allowed, however that does not seem to fit my use case.

Comment: How about `Literal["1", "2", "3"]`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I would prefer a solution that updates dynamically.

Comment: Ok, so I am assuming you then don't want to allow _any_ `str` as the type. Then please explain the use case for this and why you would need _specifically_ the value in `myfunc` rather than simply the enum member itself.

Comment: I am using features which return a value associated with an enum's member, e.g. dropdowns and radio buttons. I cannot make these features return an enum member. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to artificially restrict yourself and demand for functions to only accept enum *values* specifically.

If you want `myfunc` to do something with the value of the member of the `Colour` enum, you should still let it take the enum member as an argument:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Literal


class Colour(Enum):
    Red = "1"
    Blue = "2"
    Green = "3"


def f(colour: Colour) -> None:
    print(colour.value.center(5, "-"))


def g(colour: Literal[Colour.Blue, Colour.Green]) -> None:
    print(colour.value * 5)


f(Colour.Red)
g(Colour.Green)
```

Output:

```
--1--
33333
```

Moreover, if you want, you can [mix in](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing) `str` specifically as the supertype for your enum members. Then they can essentially be treated as strings for most intents and purposes.

In this code I don't access the member `.value`:

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Literal


class Colour(str, Enum):  # notice the order of inheritance
    Red = "1"
    Blue = "2"
    Green = "3"


def f(colour: Colour) -> None:
    print(colour.center(5, "-"))  # `colour` is of type `str`


def g(colour: Literal[Colour.Blue, Colour.Green]) -> None:
    print(colour * 5)  # `colour` is of type `str`


f(Colour.Red)
g(Colour.Green)
```

Same output.

The order of inheritance actually guarantees that all `str` methods will be present and work as expected on all enum members.

It would surprise me, if you could not use those enum members anywhere in place of "regular" `str` objects.

You can verify the type, if you do `isinstance(Colour.Red, str)`. The members are now subtypes of `str`. If you want some other concrete data type for the members, you can use that too.